# Why was my question (and my education) heavily attacked/interrogated by people who did not even comment on my Content?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions

**Does anybody have any answer/comment/evaluation of https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/57223/in-congressional-hearings-what-law-policy-dictates-how-to-record-connectivity-is, for my actual words, by their actual content?** I asked multiple times for the "readers" to repeat a single word I said, and none were able to show they're reading my question (and the contents therein) while they're passing quick judgement (I had mere minutes/hours and then boom) on me as an individual.

**Please may somebody help me direct/address the rowdy crowd who attacked me for https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/57223/in-congressional-hearings-what-law-policy-dictates-how-to-record-connectivity-is** to my comment at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/549844/meaning-of-mickey-the-boob#comment1353842_549844 so they're able to read my educational credentials before *attacking me with guesses*?

I am/was always public with identity, I publicly repeated/reposted my official school transcript to https://twitter.com/prosodyContext/status/1320509938515456005, https://i.stack.imgur.com/eop6r.jpg and https://www.facebook.com/prosody/posts/10101251550325394 (as linked in the comment link above originally) so others do not feel compelled to impulsively interrogate me with *officially-spoken, defamatory, demeaning, and ***flagrant guessing***.*

**I am using my *real voice* and *real identity/name*, I was not asked a single word about the words I used in my actual *content*.**

Answer (score 5):

I've read your linked question word for word 4 times now and I am no closer to understanding what you were asking now than I was on the first go. Something about latency and outages when using Zoom for Congressional debates is the best I can come up with.

I cannot see that you or your educational credentials were attacked except possibly by a single comment which described your question as a "rant" - I don't think that was a fair categorisation. However, that question and to a lesser extent this one are not very coherent and are certainly not clear and to the point. There was also a comment that assumed that you have limited English proficiency - I don't believe that was an attack on you or your credentials but a reasonable inference based on the English usage displayed in the question.

Other comments on the post raised germaine issues with your post in a polite and respectful manner. Your comments in response, however, seem aggressive. For example "Maybe the readers/moderators so far do not have the technical expertise to understand the connections being made here specifically" and "What technical expertise do you have (specific competence) with the issues I am speaking about here?"

I don't see that anyone made any "guesses" since nobody attempted an answer before the post was closed by 3 members of the community including myself. This was approximately 5 hours after it was first posted. After it was closed you made no edits to clarify what you were asking in the 10 days before the system automatically deleted it. Five days later, you post this question on meta.

I'm sorry that you feel hurt by this but I cannot see anything that justifies your claim of a "rowdy crowd" who are "attacking me with guesses". The criticism was directed at the question and was thoroughly merited.

Comment: I addressed your first paragraph, by delineating each sentence by number, with annotations in my answer https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1085/why-was-my-question-and-my-education-heavily-attacked-interrogated-by-people-w/1088#1088. The introductory paragraph in my response goes to answer for the merit of my reaction to how I was (or may have an appropriate right to feel) attacked not for my *content*. (I wish we encouraged editing, and not comments attacking my merit as a whole, and I would like to edit my question with the said annotations please.)

Comment: I have deleted your answer because it isn't an answer to this question - it's a commentary on your original question. We are a Q&A site, answers have to answer the question. We are not a forum so we don't want/need to-and-fro discussion. If you want to workshop your question  you can use the chatroom here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113885/question-quality-improvement

Comment: I iterated my answer to be in answer form, something mirroring your own. Please reopen.

Comment: Your "Something about..." turn of phrase you're using to converse, is good, so I copied that for my annotated answer like you. Should I just comment or flag my own answer here, I've never flagged before, and I've barely used meta ever in a decade of SE, there are not any good clear instructions in the dialogue boxes.

Answer (score 4):

Your argumentation, in @DaleM answer, to reopen the original question is not convincing.

Your supplied sample in [Meaning of "Mickey the Boob"? - English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/549844/meaning-of-mickey-the-boob) does not serve your argumenation well:

> The major search engines Google, Bing, and Yahoo do not have any definitional information in English, even though it's been 50 years.
>
> Speaking as an American born American citizen American English speaker (said in as single breath/string like many presidents at a debate would) with an exactly 3.69 GPA High School Diploma, and a year of University (like Mark Zuckerberg), who had both parents speaking legal and engineering English 100% of the time, my best/educated guess is that "Mickey" is the male Mickey Mouse and "Boob" is obviously the female human part, which is then confusing the process because of the male/female dichotomy differentials (which could be the meaning is pejorative and condescending maybe a curse word too?), so the meaning is difficult to define by ear.

It shows that your writing style is not only consistent, but also difficult to follow.

The same is true for your facebook post: [My "3.69 GPA" calculated with "Math" (Do the... - Prosody Vereable Context | Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/prosody/posts/10101251550325394), where your Grammer/Comp is shown with 95 (out of 100, I assume) for 2001/2.

With 95%, you should know that dictionaries exist (and can be found using google) :

- [Definition of Boob at Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/boobs)

  - *noun*: a stupid person; fool; dunce
  - *noun **Slang***: a female breast

The [given answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/549848) (that you haven't yet accepted), confirms the main dictionary definition:

> In this context he is likely referring to a male character who is by nature foolish and unfortunate. It would have nothing to do with female anatomy.

So doubts about your *limited English proficiency* (as expressed in one comment) is not without justification.

So as long as your [law question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/57223/in-congressional-hearings-what-law-policy-dictates-how-to-record-connectivity-is) remains in it's present form, it cannot be properly answered since it is, for the most part, simply not clear, to others, what your are asking.

Comment: I asked https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1085/why-was-my-question-and-my-education-heavily-attacked-interrogated-by-people-w/1088#comment2768_1087 to edit my question with my https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1085/why-was-my-question-and-my-education-heavily-attacked-interrogated-by-people-w/1088#1088 annotations.

Comment: I do not want to combine comments for these questions directly, but for the record I asked for https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-meaning "Phrase Meaning" (the original question tag written) which is *not* in the dictionary.

Comment: Difficult to read you as well :), I missed you said "reopen the question" when the issue is "reopen the answer" actually. Did you mistype that (technically there is now a closed question and a closed answer, which compliment eachother)? I understand the Q&A (and meta versus reg) format here is difficult.